# GCM are not getting received and get Stored on GCM server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We are sending 25000 GCM message at single run to 25000 different devices using HTTP, In report on Google Console what we are seeing is Stored 73% Sent 2% My question is why GCM is Storing 73% of messages at there end? After 2 days also messages are not get delivered to 20,000 devices, Why this happening ?

Comment: I guess the stored one are the messages which will be sent when the channels will be made free for them,as GCM doesn't support real time messaging.

Comment: In addition, I think you need to batch the requests. I remember reading somewhere that you needed to have up to maximum of 1000 messages per batch. Then again, I disliked GCM's delays so much I ended up using my own queue with mqtt which seems to be working fine for now.

Comment: @kha I am making the request batch of 1000.

Comment: @Shiv Then I'm afraid I can't help. I had a lot of problems with GCM and decided not to use it, ranging from timeouts to no acknowledgements and missed notifications.